# .AuthWithPassword() Not Working

Tags: javascript

For some reason it gives me the error :

> TypeError: Auth.authWithPassword is not a function
>       at Scope.$scope.signIn

I dont really understand,Please help! **[Here](https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/chattapp)** is my cloud9 file.

And here is my loginController.js:

```
app.controller('loginController' , ["$firebaseAuth", "$scope", "Auth", "Ref", 

    function($firebaseAuth, $scope, Auth, Ref){

    $scope.signIn = function(){

        Auth.authWithPassword({
            "email": $scope.logInEmail,
            "password": $scope.logInPassword
        } , function(error, userData){

            if(error){

                switch(error.code){

                    default:
                        alert("Error Because of " + error)
                        break;
                }

            }

            else{

                AuthService.User.email = $scope.logInEmail;
                AuthService.User.password = $scope.logInPassword;
                AuthService.User.uid = userData.ui;
                alert("Succesfully Logged In!")

            }

        })

    }


    }]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The message only says that when you do `Auth.authWithPassword`, `authWithPassword` is not a function and can't be called. Maybe it's `undefined` or maybe it's something else (like an object or a string).